# respond_to with format.js is not working for new action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and I have I am using MongoDB with the Mongoid gem.  I have a model that `embeds_many todo_items`.  When I want to create a new one and show the form using jquery, I defined things as such:

config/routes.rb

```
...
  resources :data do
    resources :todo_items#, shallow: true
  end
...
```

app/models/datum.rb:

```
class Datum
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :user_id, type: Integer

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  embeds_many :todo_items
end
```

app/models/todo_item.rb

```
class TodoItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :task, type: String
  field :content, type: String

  validates :task, presence: true

  embedded_in :datum, inverse_of: :todo_items
end
```

app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @todo = TodoItem.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @datum = Datum.find(params[:datum_id])
    @todo = @datum.todo_items.create!(params[:todo])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

inside app/views/data/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Add ToDo', new_datum_todo_item_path(@datum.id), remote: true %>
```

app/views/data/todo_items/new.js.erb:

```
$('.panel-body').append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form', @todo) %>")
```

When I click on this link, I am receiving a strange error on the `respond_to` line in my `todo_items_controller` for the `new` action (line 4):

[image: error message]

(I do notice the type of this request is being displayed as text/plain, which doesn't seem right)

````
SyntaxError at /data/532799016a616b1786040000/todo_items/new
============================================================

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>

app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb, line 4
------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
    1   class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
    2     def new
    3       @todo = TodoItem.new
>   4       respond_to do |format|
    5         format.js
    6       end
    7     end
    8   
    9     def create
```

App backtrace
-------------

 - app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb:4:in `new'

Full backtrace
--------------

 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:299:in `'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:299:in `compile'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:248:in `block in compile!'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:236:in `compile!'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `block in render'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
 - /home/jake/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
 - activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:191:in `respond_to'
 - app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb:4:in `new'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__3035648896614723876__process_action__callbacks'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
 - activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4018668017969335281__call__callbacks'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
 - better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
 - better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
 - better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 - railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 - railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
 - railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 - activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
 - railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
 - railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 - /home/jake/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 - /home/jake/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 - /home/jake/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
````

Could I get some help?  I would really appreciate it :)

### UPDATE:

The answer below definitely did the trick.  There was just a few small changes that needed to happen to get it to work all the way!  First, the `todo_items_controller`'s `new` action needs this line added: `@datum = Datum.find(params[:datum_id])`.  Then add another local variable to the `render` call of the `_form.html.erb` partial.  Then, in the partial, I had to replace the `todo` input to the `form_for` with an array that includes the `datum` and the new `todo`: `bootstrap_form_for([datum, todo]) ...`

Comment: The problem might be in the js file. Could you please share that.

Comment: added that just now :)  Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$('.panel-body').append("<%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'form',:locals => { :todo => @todo }) %>")
```

Rails is getting confused with the syntax. As you are mixing hash `partial: 'form'` with `@todo`(non-hash)

You'll have to update the partial to use `todo` variable instead of `@todo`.

Comment: actually, this seemed to get me closer, thank you for the suggestion.  Now my form in the partial is at issue as it cannot find the method `todo_items_path` when I have `bootstrap_form_for(todo)...`

Comment: No Problem. :) Do you have `todo_item_path` defined in your routes?

Comment: I have added the part of my `routes.rb` file that defines those resources.  If I `embed_many :todo_items`, does that not allow me to use those embedded models in a `form_for`?

Comment: Got it!  The `form_for` needs an array that includes the `datum` and the new `todo` item.  I'm going to mark your answer as THE answer and also add an update to my question with the additional changes required to get it to work :)  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You have nested resources so no, you don't have `todo_item_path`. Run `rake routes` to see the list of available routes. You'll find route like data_todo_item_path instead. And you need to pass @data to the partial.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :)